# Shouldn't this "if statement" cause a bounce?

Tags: javascript, canvas

The *if statement* in question is:

```
if (
  this.y + this.radius == lineInfo.loneSy && 
  this.x + this.radius > lineInfo.loneSx && 
  this.x + this.radius < lineInfo.loneEx
)
{
  this.dy = -this.dy; //linebounce
}
```

I know for sure that the first two conditions work properly because if I omit the third conditional of: `this.x + this.radius < lineInfo.loneEx`, the ball bounces as expected, however when I add the third conditional in an attempt to constrict its bounce to only within the length of the line; the ball doesn't bounce at all - even though it should.

The entire code for reference is:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
let c = canvas.getContext('2d'); //c = super object (methods / functions) 2d

const sceneObjects = [];
let lineReact = {
  jitter: false,
  hitOne: false,
  hitTwo: false,
  hitThree: false,
  hitFour: false
}
let lineInfo = {
  loneSx: 0,
  loneSy: 0,
  loneEx: 0,
  loneEy: 0
}

window.addEventListener('load',
  function(e){
    lineReact.jitter == true ? (lineReact.jitter = false) : (lineReact.jitter = true);

    if (lineReact.jitter == true){
      setTimeout(function(){
        lineReact.jitter = false;
        console.log("Time lapse " + lineReact.jitter);
      }, 300);
    }
    console.log(lineReact.jitter);
  }
)

function Square(x, y, width, height, color){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.color = color;

  this.draw = function(){
    c.fillStyle = this.color;
    c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }

  this.update = function(){
    this.draw();
  }
}

function Line(startX, startY, endX, endY, color, lNumber){

  this.startX = startX;
  this.startY = startY;
  this.endX = endX;
  this.endY = endY;
  this.color = color;

  this.lockSx = this.startX;
  this.lockSy = this.startY;
  this.lockEx = this.endX;
  this.lockEy = this.endY;

  this.draw = function(){
    c.beginPath();
    c.strokeStyle = this.color;
    c.moveTo(this.startX, this.startY);
    c.lineTo(this.endX, this.endY);
    c.stroke();
  }

  this.update = function(){

    if (lineReact.jitter == false){
      this.color = "white";
      this.startX = this.lockSx;
      this.startY = this.lockSy;
      this.endX = this.lockEx;
      this.endY = this.lockEy;
    } else {

      if(lNumber == 1){
        lineInfo.loneSx = this.lockSx;
        lineInfo.loneSy = this.lockSy;
        lineInfo.loneEx = this.lockEx;
        lineInfo.loneEy = this.lockEy;


        this.startX -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        this.startY += Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        this.endX += Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        this.endY += Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        this.color = "red";
      }
      if(lNumber == 2){
        this.startX -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        this.startY -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        this.endX -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        this.endY += Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        this.color = "red";
      }
      if(lNumber == 3){
        this.startX -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        this.startY -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        this.endX += Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        this.endY -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        this.color = "red";
      }
      if(lNumber == 4){
        this.startX += Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        this.startY -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        this.endX += Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        this.endY += Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        this.color = "red";
      }
    }
    this.draw();
    //console.log('test read ' + lineInfo.loneSx);
  }

}

function Circle(x, y, dx, dy, radius){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.dx = dx;
  this.dy = dy;
  this.radius = radius;

  this.draw = function(){
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    c.strokeStyle = 'black';
    c.fillStyle = 'black';
    c.fill();
    c.stroke();
  }

  this.update = function(){
    if (this.x + this.radius > canvas.width || this.x - this.radius < 0){
      this.dx = -this.dx; // wallbounce
    }
    if (this.y + this.radius > canvas.height || this.y - this.radius < 0){
      this.dy = -this.dy; // wallbounce
    }
    if (
      this.y + this.radius == lineInfo.loneSy &&
      this.x + this.radius > lineInfo.loneSx &&
      this.x + this.radius < lineInfo.loneEx
    )
    {
      this.dy = -this.dy; //linebounce
    }

    this.x += this.dx; //velocity
    this.y += this.dy; //velocity
    this.draw();
  }

}

let square = new Square(280, 280, 40, 40, "pink");
let circle = new Circle(245, 195, 1, 1, 6);
let lineOne = new Line(280, 270, 320, 270, "white", 1);
let lineTwo = new Line(330, 280, 330, 320, "white", 2);
let lineThree = new Line(280, 330, 320, 330, "white", 3);
let lineFour = new Line(270, 280, 270, 320, "white", 4);

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  square.update();
  lineOne.update();
  lineTwo.update();
  lineThree.update();
  lineFour.update();
  circle.update();
}

animate();
```

```css
  body {
      background-color: black;
      margin: 0;
    }
    #myCanvas {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      background-color: #385D72;
      margin: -300px 0 0 -300px;
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600">
```

Comment: I tried your code: the ball bounces on the upper line when you set its x to 235, what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `||` instead of `&&`:

```
if (
  this.y + this.radius == lineInfo.loneSy && 
  (this.x + this.radius < lineInfo.loneSx || this.x + this.radius > lineInfo.loneEx)
)
{
  this.dy = -this.dy; //linebounce
}
```

With `&&` you're testing if both conditions are true, but it's impossible for both to be true at the same time (the ball can't be both to the left of the line and to the right of the line).

Comment: I tried your suggestion, it doesn't work - it bounces no matter where it is in relation to the line.

Comment: @Ghoyos Did you add the additional parenthesis too?

Comment: @Ghoyos I think your `<` and `>` are backwards too. I edited my answer and flipped them.